# Facebook displays the wrong og:image tag when sharing

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

Upon sharing a link on Facebook with og:image and og:video tags it will, under the right conditions, consistently display the wrong thumbnail image. Our clients are having this problem but unfortunately I cannot consistently replicate the conditions under which this issue occurs.

Go to the QVC UK Facebook page and look for video shares ([example post](http://www.facebook.com/QVCUK/posts/10152052509644656)). You'll see that the thumbnail for the video is the QVC logo when it should be the image given in the og:image tag. When putting the link through Facebook's debug tool the correct image is displayed with no content warnings or errors. This only seems to be happening when the URL is shared for the first time as subsequent shares will display the correct image. The image is present on our CDN before the URL is shared on Facebook. When I did manage to luckily replicate this issue; running the debugger before sharing on Facebook did not seem to solve the problem.

Am I missing something obvious, is there something wrong with my meta tags or could this be a potential facebook bug?

I've seen that multiple people are recording the same sort of problem on Facebook however only [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204880016332273) has been left open (as of June 21st). In a related bug report Facebook mention that their crawlers don't only look at the image in the og tag but also look for other relevant images within the page.

Is it possible that it is seeing the QVC logo used so many times on the page that it decides to randomly overwrite the one specified?

Thanks

-- UPDATE

This only seems to be a problem when sharing to Facebook pages as opposed to a user's timeline. Changing the image URL seems to have temporarily fixed the problem. This looks like a Facebook bug

Comment: looks like facebook fixed this issue...